# Question deleted

Tags: discussion, off-topic, deleted-questions

My question here https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7098/is-there-enough-evidence-in-bible-quran-that-earth-is-indeed-5000-years-old
was deleted. Ok it was closed as duplicate first and  I commented it was not a duplicate. There was a similar question asking, is the world really 6000 year old. My question was is there enough evidence in bible that the earth is 6000 years old. It was mostly theological (ofcourse rational theological) question. Of course I dont want to ask it on religius form because I want sound minded people to answer it, not religious fanatics who come up with some lame explanation that yes bible has tones of proof that earth is 6000 years old.

My question was close and then deleted? Was it such an off-topic question that it was deleted?

Can some shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably should have been closed as off-topic instead of a duplicate to avoid confusion. The question whether the earth is 6000 years old would be a duplicate, the question what the Bible or Quran say on the topic is a theological question that is off-topic here.

From the viewpoint of scientific skepticism, the Bible cannot be evidence for what is essentially a geological, astronomical or physical question: the age of the earth and the universe. What the bible says on a specific topic is a theology question.

Questions closed as off-topic are routinely deleted after a while.

Comment: Is looking for references in bible also theological also? The question did not mean to prove earth is 6000 years old because bible says so. The question meant do we have enough evidence in bible that specifically says the earth is 5000 years old. To me this is not a religious issue but a plain logical one to find adequate quotes/references from bible that the earth is indeed 5000 years old. I am ok with off-topic if it sound religous but I am not a very religious guy but like to investigate.

Comment: Isn't there a Biblical web site on SE somewhere. It probably should have been migrated there

Comment: Looking for biblical references is an excellent topic for hermeneutics.stackexchange.com, but it is out of scope for Skeptics.SE, which is targeted at finding scientific evidence for or against claims.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question was, but from your comment to Fabians answer, it seems to me, that you're asking, whether the bible claims the earth is 5-6000y old, in contrast to another age, claimed in the bible, or a missing claim.

AFAIK, YEC's calculate the age by ages of men with an uninterrupted genealogy from Adam to Jesus, and ages, when their sons were born.

I didn't verify myself, that their claim is correct, and without much room for interpretation, but afaik, christians who don't take the bible literally, don't believe in the 'biblical ages' of ancient jews, but they don't question the individual additions. But I'm not deep into that question.

However:

- It is a public claim, imho.
- It is a provable question, which might have an objective answer.
- It might fit better to 'biblical hermeneutics' but that page might not exist very long (low traffic).

Conclusion: Undelete, but make it more clear, that you aren't asking for believing in the words of the bible, nor for evidence or proof mentioned in the bible, but just, whether this is or is not a claim of the bible.

Comment: The question was: "Is there enough evidence in Bible (old testament, new testament) or Quran that earth is indeed 5000 or 6000 years old?" - it was closed as an exact duplicate of http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1438/is-the-earth-6000-years-old

Comment: I think I understood why it was closed.